# Shows Application Error after successful deploy of Spring Web MVC project in Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku

> Server log while deploying code

```
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
remote: [INFO] Total time: 6.068 s
remote: [INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-04T18:35:42+00:00
remote: [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/164M
remote: [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 60.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://sometext.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/sometext.git
   7839c97..2b14519  master -> master
```

---

> Result of page request after hitting the url in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Do you find any error in Heroku logs?

Comment: There was no any error logs.

Comment: Let's start searching "that black cat" in the dark room, We may find it... :-(

Comment: I have tried with new project just to print Hello World, but the result was same. That black cat might be invisible too in the dark room.

Comment: So, the problem is not at the application side, but at the heroku side, now, you can search the cat in that part of the room :-)